# How to set ViewBox background?

Tags: c#, wpf, background, viewbox

I need to set the background of my `System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox`, but the property is missing.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put your viewbox inside a control that supports the background property:

```
<Border Background="Red">
   <ViewBox />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 4):

Put it in a `Border` and set its `Background`.